# Proper parsing of a html-page with escaped ascii-strings

Tags: python, html, parsing, web, web-crawler

I'm currently working on a *crawler* in *Python*, which is already crawling a genre page on http://lyrics.wikia.com/ to get all bands and albums and then crawls these links to get the links to specific songs to finally parse the lyrics and put them in a database so it can help me with an analysis on lyrical content.

I got my crawler to do all these steps, but when I parse the html from the lyric page with *urllib* and *beautifulsoup* I get weird content. I investigated this and there seems to be a script which stops people from crawling? When looking at the html-source code, the lyrics are cyphered like that below. I dont know what to call that so sadly I couldn't quite do further research by myself without knowing what to look for.

```
<div class='lyricbox'>&#73;&#116;&#32;&#119;&#97;&#115;&#32;&#119;&#104;&#101;&#110;&#32;&#73;&#32;&#114;&#101;&#97;&#108;&#105;&#122;&#101;&#100;<br />&#116;&#104;&#97;&#116;&#32;&#108;&#105;&#102;&#101;&#32;&#104;&#97;&#115;&#32;&#110;&#111;&#32;&#109;&#101;&#97;&#110;&#105;&#110;&#103;<br />&#110;&#111;&#32;&#112;&#117;&#114;&#112;&#111;&#115;&#101;&#44;&#32;&#110;&#111;&#32;&#113;&#117;&#97;&#114;&#114;&#121;<br />&#46;&#46;&#46;&#110;&#111;&#32;&#97;&#110;&#115;&#119;&#101;&#114;&#101;&#115;&#46;&#46;&#46;<br /><br />&#65;&#110;&#100;&#32;&#97;&#108;&#108;&#32;&#116;&#104;&#101;&#32;&#100;&#114;&#101;&#97;&#114;&#121;&#32;&#110;&#105;&#103;&#104;&#116;<br />&#116;&#104;&#97;&#116;&#32;&#104;&#97;&#100;&#32;&#98;&#101;&#102;&#97;&#108;&#108;&#101;&#110;&#32;&#97;&#99;&#114;&#111;&#115;&#115;<br />&#116;&#104;&#101;&#32;&#108;&#97;&#110;&#100;<br />&#73;&#32;&#115;&#108;&#105;&#112;&#112;&#101;&#100;&#32;&#105;&#110;&#116;&#111;&#32;&#97;&#32;&#114;&#101;&#118;&#101;&#114;&#121;<br />&#97;&#32;&#119;&#101;&#98;&#32;&#111;&#102;&#32;&#104;&#117;&#109;&#97;&#110;&#32;&#104;&#97;&#110;&#100;<br /><br />&#89;&#111;&#117;&#32;&#108;&#111;&#110;&#103;&#101;&#100;&#32;&#116;&#111;&#32;&#115;&#111;&#97;&#114;&#32;&#117;&#112;&#32;&#104;&#105;&#103;&#104;<br />&#116;&#111;&#32;&#99;&#97;&#114;&#101;&#115;&#115;&#32;&#116;&#104;&#101;&#32;&#115;&#105;&#108;&#107;&#121;&#32;&#119;&#105;&#110;&#100;&#115;<br />&#116;&#111;&#32;&#101;&#109;&#98;&#114;&#97;&#99;&#101;&#32;&#97;&#110;&#100;&#32;&#107;&#105;&#115;&#115;&#32;&#97;&#115;&#32;&#108;&#111;&#118;&#101;&#114;&#115;<br />&#46;&#46;&#46;&#116;&#104;&#101;&#32;&#101;&#116;&#104;&#101;&#114;&#46;&#46;&#46;<br /><br
```

When investigating with the google chrome developer tool, the lyrics are readable.

The example page was: http://lyrics.wikia.com/wiki/Agalloch:The_Wilderness

**So long story short:** 
What is this? Where does it come from? How do I find a workaround? (keep in mind that I want to do that with around 20000 pages, so preferably it has to be fast and/or iteratable

*Thanks in advance!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should post code that we can help debug, your not using the right encoding scheme i'm guessing.  `Import requests` works for me:

```
>>> import requests
>>> import bs4
>>> url = "http://lyrics.wikia.com/wiki/Agalloch:The_Wilderness"
>>> req = requests.get(url)
>>> soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(req.text, "html.parser")
>>> lyrics = soup.find("div", {"class":"lyricbox"})
>>> lyrics.get_text().rstrip()
```

This will return:

```
"It was when [... ] the cosmos...Forevermore..."
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this works! I was using almost the same, except I was using urllib to get "req", lxml as a parser instead of html.parser and I didnt use get_text().rstrip(). I think I'm not going to edit my post to show what I my code was since this is now answered (or should I still?)

Comment: You're fine, the question is still the same people will get responses like yours in the future and this thread has some other great answers to encoding/decoding

Answer (score 0):

Those are HTML encoded characters : http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm

You just need to decode them. There's probably an existing tool you can use to decode them.

Comment: I just learned that my module seems to usually do so thanks to  Tonys answer. Thank you nevertheless

Answer (score 0):

So, it turns out that those are integer values of ascii characters. In your script, you could do something like this to get printable ascii back!

```
>>> a = '&#73;&#116;&#32;&#119;&#97;&#115;&#32;&#119;&#104;&#101;&#110;&#32;&#73;&#32;&#114;&#101;&#97;&#108;&#105;&#122;&#101;&#100;'
>>> ''.join(map(chr,map(int,a.replace('&#','').split(';')[:-1])))                        
'It was when I realized'
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, I dont unterstand why exactly youre doing that, but i'll read into the theory of ascii-characters so that I will in the future.

Comment: I'm basically taking the raw string with all of the extra stuff in it, removing all instances of '&#' and then splitting the remaining string into a list on every occurrance of a semicolon. There is a semicolon on the end, which will result in an empty element, so we ignore the last character with `[:-1]`. Since all elements are string, you want to map those all to integers, and then map the resulting integers to the ascii representation of the ints. You end up with a list of characters. If you join the elements with an empty character, you will end up with the string you're looking for.

Comment: That sounds plausible, thank you for the explanation. I might take a further look into the map command

Comment: `map` is awesome, especially in conjunction with `lambda` functions

Answer (score 0):

These are escaped HTML entiries, e.g `&amp;` for `&`. and `&amp;` has a decimal and hexadecimal equivalent representation. Your text is riddled with decimal. Here is how you do it.

```
import html
s = "<div class='lyricbox'>&#73;&#116;&#32;&#119;&#97;&#115;&#32;&#119;&#104;&#101;&#110;&#32;&#73;&#32;&#114;&#101;&#97;&#108;&#105;&#122;&#101;&#100;<br />&#116;&#104;&#97;&#116;&#32;&#108;&#105;&#102;&#101;&#32;&#104;&#97;&#115;&#32;&#110;&#111;&#32;&#109;&#101;&#97;&#110;&#105;&#110;&#103;<br />&#110;&#111;&#32;&#112;&#117;&#114;&#112;&#111;&#115;&#101;&#44;&#32;&#110;&#111;&#32;&#113;&#117;&#97;&#114;&#114;&#121;<br />&#46;&#46;&#46;&#110;&#111;&#32;&#97;&#110;&#115;&#119;&#101;&#114;&#101;&#115;&#46;&#46;&#46;<br /><br />&#65;&#110;&#100;&#32;&#97;&#108;&#108;&#32;&#116;&#104;&#101;&#32;&#100;&#114;&#101;&#97;&#114;&#121;&#32;&#110;&#105;&#103;&#104;&#116;<br />&#116;&#104;&#97;&#116;&#32;&#104;&#97;&#100;&#32;&#98;&#101;&#102;&#97;&#108;&#108;&#101;&#110;&#32;&#97;&#99;&#114;&#111;&#115;&#115;<br />&#116;&#104;&#101;&#32;&#108;&#97;&#110;&#100;<br />&#73;&#32;&#115;&#108;&#105;&#112;&#112;&#101;&#100;&#32;&#105;&#110;&#116;&#111;&#32;&#97;&#32;&#114;&#101;&#118;&#101;&#114;&#121;<br />&#97;&#32;&#119;&#101;&#98;&#32;&#111;&#102;&#32;&#104;&#117;&#109;&#97;&#110;&#32;&#104;&#97;&#110;&#100;<br /><br />&#89;&#111;&#117;&#32;&#108;&#111;&#110;&#103;&#101;&#100;&#32;&#116;&#111;&#32;&#115;&#111;&#97;&#114;&#32;&#117;&#112;&#32;&#104;&#105;&#103;&#104;<br />&#116;&#111;&#32;&#99;&#97;&#114;&#101;&#115;&#115;&#32;&#116;&#104;&#101;&#32;&#115;&#105;&#108;&#107;&#121;&#32;&#119;&#105;&#110;&#100;&#115;<br />&#116;&#111;&#32;&#101;&#109;&#98;&#114;&#97;&#99;&#101;&#32;&#97;&#110;&#100;&#32;&#107;&#105;&#115;&#115;&#32;&#97;&#115;&#32;&#108;&#111;&#118;&#101;&#114;&#115;<br />&#46;&#46;&#46;&#116;&#104;&#101;&#32;&#101;&#116;&#104;&#101;&#114;&#46;&#46;&#46;<br /><br>"
html.unescape(s)
"<div class='lyricbox'>It was when I realized<br />that life has no meaning<br />no purpose, no quarry<br />...no answeres...<br /><br />And all the dreary night<br />that had befallen across<br />the land<br />I slipped into a revery<br />a web of human hand<br /><br />You longed to soar up high<br />to caress the silky winds<br />to embrace and kiss as lovers<br />...the ether...<br /><br>"
```

A good parser will take care of this, even the minimalistic `HTMLParser` takes care of this.

Comment: @sorh what parser you were using bdw?

Comment: I was using beautifulsoup with lxml. I still think I messed some more things up, as you can see under Tony's answer

Comment: @sorh I see, bdw I extensively use regex or HTMLParser, if I am lazy. So, not familiar with particular subtlities of BS.

Comment: At first I used regex as well, but lots of people told me that there are huge problems with regex and html, so I should just use beautifulsoup instead to save me all the trouble

Comment: @sorh those people are correct. But it finally boils down to if your target text content is stateful. If it is, then you have to implement/use a state machine i.e a parser. But I deal with getting tiny snippets from loads of pages. So a regex is terse, nifty and makes you feel like a ninja.